# Updating column having index causing Deadlock

Tags: mysql, database-design, index, innodb, deadlock

My update statement:

```
Update XyzTable set state ='second' where pgmNumber = 'prog123' and state = 'first'
```

Both `state` and `pgmNumber` columns has individual index.

Deadlock is happening even if above query running concurrently  with different `pgmNumber`.

There is single row for each `pgmNumber`

What would be the best way to resolve the issue

Comment: Innodb should not  lock the hole table, what are you using for your table?

Comment: It's mysql db, state column is having index so two concurrent updates are getting in deadlock because of page lock due to state column index

Comment: Please add more details. For example, output of LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK  section from INNODB STATUS. Do your transactions contain more than one statement?

Comment: Yes it contains more than one statement & it would be difficult to separate them out. Page level lock is happening because of state index column, removing index will solve the problem but we can't do, is there some other way?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677988/updating-column-having-index-causing-deadlock , where it probably belongs.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way to resolve the issue

You should create a compound index (unique if appropriate) on `(pgmNumber, state)`. The index only on `state` is useless because of the low cardinality of that domain.

Generally only one index can be used for executing statements like yours, and in your scenario: "Both `state` and `pgmNumber` columns has individual index" it causes locks on more rows than necessary, thus leading to deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio, but it's pretty large table & we can not do any change on index level as its being used at many places & by many team. So would there be any other solution

Comment: Neither the table size nor it being used by other applications has any bearing on your ability to create proper indexes for it. Deadlocks are an indication of flaws in your application or database design, they cannot be resolved by magic.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but if changes then it may cause issue to other apps,                                   if we use index hint in query like use index pgmNumber or force index pgmNumber will that solve deadlock problem?

Comment: That's exactly what you have your test environment for, is it not

Comment: It's happening very rarely so hard to reproduce, though we are trying but if some one already tried hint index to avoid deadlock then it would give some idea.                                 What's your opinion will that help?